# How to install maven in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, installation, eclipse-plugin, osx-mavericks

Install maven in Mac using

brew install maven,

if you don't have Homebrew in your system you have another way to install maven in your system.

Comment: This is normally not necessary because recent versions of Eclipse come with m2e (Maven plugin) prebundled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the Help from the top menu in Eclipse and select ‘Install New Software..‘
[image]

How to Install Maven in Eclipse IDE

2) Click on the Add button on the newly opened window.
 [image]

3) In the Name box, type ‘Maven‘ and in the Location box, type ‘http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/‘
[image]

4) A check-box will appear in the pop window, Check the check-box and click on Next button.
[image]

Comment: the URL is broken, the correct URL is -https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest/